# How to access boot file configured axios from Quasar V2 Composition API setup function?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

How to access boot file configured axios from Quasar V2 Composition API setup function, without importing axios in every file?

Since this.$axios can be used only for Options API, I tried to access through the context parameter of setup function.

Even though it works, context.root is now deprecated in Vue 3.

I do not want to import axios in every file as shown in the example at https://next.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/ajax-requests

For setup method access, I think it is still not implemented since mentioned as a TODO activity at https://next.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#examples-of-appropriate-usage-of-boot-files

Similar to axios, usage of vue-i18n also from boot file is an issue for me.

```
 setup (props, context) {
         
    context.root.$axios({
    method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/storemgr/item/3',
      }).then((response: any) => {
          console.log(response)
      }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
...
}
```

Below is my axios boot file contents generated by Quasar V2 CLI

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
  }
}

export default boot(({ Vue }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
})
```

Comment: Very well formed question. I would revisit this and see if it still applies. Since your original post, this might now be obsolete. I seem to recall using the `this.$axios` approach recently.

Comment: The question isn't obsolete because it involves upgrading from Quasar V1 to V2 and it breaks here where people were using `Vue.prototype` because Vue 3 does not provide a root instance.

Answer (score 4):

The only other way I found is to use [Provide/Inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html).
In my boot file, I use it like this:

```js
export default boot(({ app }) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios
    app.provide('axios', app.config.globalProperties.$axios)
})
```

In any component:

```js
setup() {
    const axios: AxiosInstance = inject('axios') as AxiosInstance
    [...]
}
```

In hindsight, I'm not quite sure if this is better than importing it.

Comment: It's definitely better! This way I can add custom attributes to an Axios instance, like the base URL. Thanks!

Comment: This URL is helpful: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/boot-files#axios

Answer (score 1):

For This worked

```
import {api} from 'boot/axios'

setup() {
    return{
        api.post('shop/', data, { #api imported that works in setup quasar
            headers: {
              Authorization: `token ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")).token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },

            onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
              console.log((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
              dialog.update({
                message: `${(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100}%`
              })
            }
          })
}
}
```